# PBH Test matrix

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

Can the matrix occurring from PBH test have rank greater than the dimension n of the state space? What does it mean for the controllability of the system?

Comment: Normally, the controllability matrix is of dimension $n$ times something. Thus, it cannot have rank bigger than $n$.

Comment: But, according to PBH test, for a matrix K = [(A-λI) B] where state space is of dimension n, if I choose a B of dimensions n by n, and rank n, wouldn't this allow my K matrix to be at least of rank n?

Comment: Of rank $n$ but not bigger. Actually, if your $B$ is $n \times n$ of full rank, then your system is controllable.

Answer (score 0):

No. As mentioned in the comments, the PBH matrix is defined to be

$$ K = [(A-\lambda I) B].$$

Since $A$ is $n\times n$ and $B$ is $n \times m$, it follows that $K$ is $n \times (n+m) $. Since the rank of a matrix cannot exceed the lesser of the column or row numbers, it follows that the rank of $K$ is at most $n$.